# Select2 Find existing or type new always show first option as blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I added a select2 and it always show first option as blank.
just below the blank option, it always shows what i type in select2 textfield. Any Idea, how i can fix it.

[image]
    = hidden_field_tag :tags // present in HAML form

```
// javascript 
$('#tags').select2
createSearchChoice: (term, data) ->
  if $(data).filter((->
      @text.localeCompare(term) == 0
    )).length == 0
    return {
      id: term
      text: term
    }
  return
multiple: false
data: [
  {
    id: 0
    text: 'story'
  }
  {
    id: 1
    text: 'bug'
  }
  {
    id: 2
    text: 'task'
  }`enter code here`
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .....

Your input field should be like this

```
%input#tags{:style => "width: 300px", :type => "hidden"}
```

Your js code should be like this

```
$("#tags").select2({
  placeholder:"Select an option",  
  createSearchChoice: function(term, data) {
    if ($(data).filter((function() {
      return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
    })).length === 0) {
      return {
        id: term,
        text: term
      };
    }
  },
  multiple: false,
  data: [
    {
      id: 0,
      text: 'story'
    }, {
      id: 1,
      text: 'bug'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: 'task'
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need to use `createSearchChoice` if you want to do this with Select2, you can just use the `tags` option. Right now you shouldn't be seeing the blank option, as you aren't passing one to Select2 at all, so this is lacking a bit of information that would explain *that* issue.

Select2 will automatically hide blank options though if you have a placeholder set, which I would always recommend. So the hacky solution is to set the `placeholder` option to whatever you want ("Select a few tags..."), but that only works if this is actually a blank option and not just a CSS issue. You can tell if it's a blank option if Select2 highlights it whenever you start searching, as it will automatically highlight the first option.

It would make more sense for this to be a CSS issue, maybe a bit too much padding somewhere, as the tag (or choice from `createSearchChoice`) should be inserted automatically at the top of the search results. So even if there was a spare blank option sitting around, it would show *under* the newly created search choice.